# My iPhone is doing math wrong

Tags: iphone, ios

See the images, it's an iPhone 6s, with iOS 10.3.2, does any one have the same issue ? It seems specific to any fraction with three digits after the comma on the denominator within spotlight:

[image]

Also, to add some information, it comes back to correct result when I add (or remove) a digit (see image)

[image]

And I have a correct result when it is with coma on both numerator and denominator:
[image]

Comment: When I enter 1,8/0.83 on my phone running iOS 10 it returns: 216.8674698795   My Region is set to United States.  It appears you may be in Québec?  What are your region settings set to?  General > Language and Region

Comment: Yes, it is french canadian. Your result is still wrong though..

Comment: Yes, results are correct with the calculator. They are also right with osx spotlight.

Comment: macOS spotlight gives me the same result but only if I type exactly as you have it 1,8/0.083  if I type 1.8/0.083 I get 19.3548387097  comma or point seems to make a difference.

Comment: I got the correct result if I use 1.8/0.083 or 1,8/0.083 with spotlight on macOS. And the correct result should be 21.68674... You got 19.35 with the exact same formula ?

Answer (score 1):

I get different results based on whether 1,8/0.083 is used or 1.8/0.083 is used both in spotlight on iOS and macOS.  It would appear that the comma <kbd>,</kbd> is ignored and the number is treated as non decimal.

Attached are the results.  One could verify if the region settings make a difference by changing them temporarily to UK or another region.

### iOS:

[image: 1,8/0.083 iOS]

[image: 1.8/0.083 iOS]

### macOS:

[image: 1,8/0.083 macOS]

[image: 1.8/0.083 macOS]

### Compare Wolfram Alpha results:

[image: wolfram alpha 1,8/0.083]

[image: Wolfram Alpha 1.8/0.083]

Comment: Interesting, your third capture shows 18/0.083 (in the results) even if you enter 1,8/0.083

Comment: I think because it ignores the , as it is not a valid decimal point.  The comma, at least on my devices, is for thousands separator. (even though it shows on the iOS spotlight version, it appears to be ignored) Answer edited